# Get a list of table references using EF7

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework

I am using EF7 and SQLite. I can get a list of table names pretty easily, but what I need is a list of table references. I want to be able to execute on each table the command `await table.Table.ExecuteDeleteAsync()`, where Table is the reference to the table.

Is this possible? I need to be able to delete all records from every table at start up.

Comment: EF is an ORM, it deals with objects and relations, not tables. A DbSet isn't a table at all and knows nothing about the actual database schema. It only knows the model that's either explicitly created in `OnModelCreating` or constructed based on naming and model conventions

Comment: Why are you using an ORM at all, if all you want is to execute `DELETE` commands on tables? The actual database connection isn't provided by EF but ADO.NET and whatever SQLite driver you used. As for `delete all records from every table at start up.` why not replace the database *file* then? SQLite is an embedded, file-based database. It means the application controls it completely, there's no separate server. You can just delete the file or replace it with a different one, eg an empty one

Comment: Please set the second as an answer and I will upvote it. As to why I am using an ORM, there is quite a lot of data relations that need to be maintained. Simpler this way. Just one, odd, need at start up.